# Unable to pass variable from my .cpp to .h class?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I have the following setup

Square.h

```
#ifndef square_h
#define square_h
#include "Shape.h"
using namespace std;

class Square : public Shape
{
     public:
              Point * points = nullptr;
              int minX = 0;
              int maxX = 0;
              
              ...

              void getMinMax(Point *points, int minX, maxX)
}
# endif
```

Square.cpp

```
...

void Square :: getMinMax(Point *points, int minX, int maxX)
{
    this->minX = points[3].x;
}

...

string Square :: toString()
{
     cout << "Minimum X : " << minX << endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
...

for(size_t i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++)
{
    cout << shapes[i]->toString();
}
```

Based on the above snippet of code, I have a function in square.cpp that I am trying to pass the minX back to .h minX variable. The idea is to allow this minX to be use in other functions declared inside .h file.

However I am always getting a 0 when I `cout` the `minX` in other functions even though my `points[3].x` has > 0.

What will be a proper way to pass by reference my `minX` to my header class variable minX?

Note: The .cpp function is just a test to see if my value is passed into .h `minX`.

Comment: I think we need to see more code, I don't see a problem with anything you've posted.

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve]? It isn't clear to me what the problem is. The function you've shown should change the value of the `minX` member in that object. Hard to say what might be going on in the code we can't see though.

Comment: i don't see problem post more code.

Comment: Hi I have added more snippet of the code which should be relevant to the problem (sorry I can't produce a reproducible example at this point). When I run the program and the main.cpp run the for loop to cout, the minimum X will always be 0.

Comment: You set `minX` but output `minY`, is that correct? How do you call `getMinMax`? Why is it called `getMinMax` when all it does is *set* a single member variable? Really, please create a [mcve] to show us. Also take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toString()` method doesn't return anything. It should return the string rather than write it to `cout`. You write the result to `cout` when you do `cout << shapes[i]->toString();`.

```
string Square :: toString()
{
    std::stringstream ret;
    ret << "Minimum X : " << minY << endl;
    return ret.str();
}
```